# When to stop training a Auixilary Classifier GAN?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gan, torch

When should I stop training an Auxiliary Classifier GAN? when the discriminator loss converges or when the auxiliary classification accuracy converges or when the Real vs Fake classifier converges to an accuracy of 50%?